# BigOh Complexity: $\frac{x^{3} + 2x}{2x + 1}$ is $O(x^2)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Show $\frac{x^{3} + 2x}{2x + 1}$ is $O(x^2)$

Can I do it like this?

Since exponent rules/laws allow this:

$\frac{x^{3} + 2x}{2x + 1}$ $=$ $\frac{1}{2}x^{2}  + 2x$

Must show a constant c>0 and k s.t

$\frac{1}{2}x^{2} + 2x$ $< c * x^{2}$

Consider $\frac{1}{2}x^{2} + 2x^{2}$ $=$ $\frac{1}{2}x^{2} + \frac{4}{2}x^{2}$

$=$ $x^{2}$($\frac{1}{2}$ $+$ $\frac{4}{2}$) = $x^{2}$$(\frac{5}{2})$

So choose c = $\frac{5}{2}$ => $\frac{x^{3} + 2x}{2x + 1}$ < $\frac{5}{2}$$x^{2}$ for any $x>k$ where $k=0$

Comment: Are you sure that the simplification $\frac{x^3 + 2x}{2x + 1} = \frac{1}{2} x^2 + 2x$ is valid? When [plotted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k9V9e.png), the two functions look quite different.

Comment: Well they are two different functions so the plots and coordinates will be different. But if the exponents rules/laws allow this doesnt it mean it should be somewhat reasonable?

Comment: What do you mean that the "exponents rules/laws allow this"? What is "this"? What "exponent rules/laws"? The equation that you have written—$\frac{x^3 + 2x}{2x + 1} = \frac{1}{2} x^2 + 2x$—is *not* identically true.

Comment: Your simplification is wrong. It looks like you just divided $2x$ into $x^3$ and $1$ into $2x$, but that's not how division works.

Comment: There is a exponent rule where if you divide $\frac{x^{3}}{2x}$ it can be equivalent to $x^{3-1}$ which is $\frac{1}{2}x^{2}$

Comment: Either way, thanks for pointing out its wrong. I am just studying and practicing Big-Oh questions and was just wondering if this is valid. Well now I know, thanks.

Comment: Yes, but you're not dividing by $2x$—you're dividing by $2x + 1$. Your mistake isn't in the order analysis; it's in the algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{x^3+2x}{2x+1}\le\frac{x^3+2x}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}x^2+1\le 2x^2$ for all $x\ge 1$